# Load part of the pdf page in ios

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, swift, xamarin

I want to load entire pdf page progressively. Basically entire page will be divided in four parts and each part will then be loaded separately. After zoom in/out, resolution will be changed of only those parts that are visible. We have have similar kind of loading in google maps as well.

So, i want to grab the image of part of the pdf page, say bottom-right part.

Comment: That's not a question, that's a list of requirements.  If you have a specific question, please ask it.  But telling you how to fulfill all of the requirements of your app is beyond the scope of SO.

Comment: ""CGRect pageRect = page.GetBoxRect (CGPDFBox.Media);"" 
This code gives me rect for entire page. Is it possible to get rect for part of the page?